Are there safety concerns with hooking an inductor to a MOSFET and generating 85V spikes from a 9V source?
Are there safety concerns with hooking an inductor to a MOSFET and generating 85V spikes from a 9V source?
Looking at the circuit below, I can generate this from a 9V battery.  Is this safe? It's on a breadboard and will come into contact with skin, hands, etc.  Will it damage a breadboard?


Be careful, 85V can easily become 300V and more, if your resistor is not connected. It hurts.

At that frequency, very little energy will pass through the main part of the torso. It might cause very minor contact burns but, nothing that won't heal in a week or so.

The breadboard will probably be fine, but anything above ~30VDC cannot be considered touch safe. In addition, the circuit you have does not regulate its output so the 85V figure could be low or high depending on the battery used, the interconnecting wiring, the MOSFET temperature, etc

Incidentally, I regularly use solderless breadboards to quickly wire up supplies of some hundreds of volts; even 2kV with extra space reserved. I can't expect they're very reliable at this, but reliability isn't important: I'm always using them under supervision. YMMV.

@TimWilliams How do you do that safely, given that all the connections are exposed? Jumper wires can easily come loose and be dangling, too.

@SRobertJames Power supplies can be turned off before touching the circuit.  Should, even ;)
